# Specified JDBC Driver com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver class not found

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, db2, classnotfoundexception

I have spent considerable time researching and trying to figure out where I have gone wrong with my configuration but am completely stuck. From the posts I have been reading the implication is that my driver is not in the classpath. I added the Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver") line to ensure that the driver is available and it loads in that line. I would really appreciate any suggestions as to what I may have missed.

my code is:

```
    public class TestHibernateConfig {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static void testConfig() {
        try {
            DB2Driver drvr = (DB2Driver) Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver").newInstance();

            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
            Session sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();

            Criteria crit = sess.createCriteria(ItemData.class);
            List items = crit.list();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I get the class not found error when my code hits:
sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="speed2db2">
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:db2://appdb:50000/MYTEST</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">myUser</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">myPass</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="speedPersistUnit">
        <class>ItemData</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:db2://appdb:50000/MYTEST"/>
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="MYSCHEMA"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="myUser"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="myPass"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

From within Eclipse I am able to connect to the database and if I go to the Hibernate perspective, I am able to browse the database schema. I am also able to use the HQL editor to load data in my class.

Edit:

```
09:35:50,338 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (http-xxxxxx-xx.xx.xx.xxxx-15081-1) HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /com/newpig/speed2DB2/hibernate.cfg.xml
09:35:50,340 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (http-xxxxxx-xx.xx.xx.xxxx-15081-1) HHH000040: Configuration resource: /com/newpig/speed2DB2/hibernate.cfg.xml
09:35:50,369 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (http-xxxxxx-xx.xx.xx.xxxx-15081-1) HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: speed2db2
09:35:52,059 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-xxxxxx-xx.xx.xx.xxxx-15081-1) HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
09:36:16,856 ERROR [] (http-xxxxxx-xx.xx.xx.xxxx-15081-1) Specified JDBC Driver com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver class not found
```

The error happens on this line.

```
 sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
```

Deployed to my .war file:
.War
|-WEB-INF
||-lib
|||-db2jcc4.jar
|||-hibernate-core-4.1.2.Final.jar
|||-hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.2.Final.jar
|||-hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar

Comment: where do you get the error and can you perhaps share the relevant stack trace, or other forms of the log ?

Comment: I added the stack trace. It does show that the config file is being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I mentioned that I am using JBoss7.1. In the end I was not able to figure out why Hibernate was failing to load the driver but got around it by switching to use JNDI and configuring the datasource in the JBoss standalone.xml instead of trying to make the connection from Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because hibernate.cfg.xml is in wrong place. You should check if it in your classpath or you can try add classpath in your method call like this.

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure(
                    "/com/mkyong/persistence/hibernate.cfg.xml")
                    .buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try moving my config file and referencing it with the path as you show. I got the same issue. You can see in my edit above that it is finding the config file. I have confirmed that db2jcc4.jar is in the lib folder in my .war on the server. Also, as stated, the Class.forName() loads the driver properly. I have also confirmed the URL is correct.